# Create columns X1-Xn depending on the contents of Columns A and B

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
```

[image]

```
df2
```

[image]

And a need add in `df1` new columns based on `df2['B']`.
In the new column, write 1 if the content of the row in column `A` contains the text from the row in column `B` for this iteration. 0 if not. we also take the name of the column from column `B`. It should probably be clearer by the example below:

[image]

Comment: If no matches were found, then the column still needs to be created, it will contain 0 everywhere

Comment: please add your data as text see [mcve] and image is _not_ reproducible

Answer (score 1):

Try this, try to print the df after every line to understand it better:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on=['N'], how='left').fillna('0')
df = df.pivot(index=['N', 'A_x'], columns=['A_y'], values=['A_y']).fillna(0)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.replace('\w+', 1, regex=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('A_y_', '', regex=True).str.replace('A_x', 'A')
df.drop(columns=['0'], inplace=True)
print(df)


   N        A  asd  asd asd  asdasd
0  1  asd asd    0        1       0
1  2      asd    1        0       0
2  3   asdasd    0        0       1
3  4      xcv    0        0       0
4  5   asdasd    0        0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
defects = df2['B'].unique()
for i in defects:
    df1[i]= df1["A"].map(lambda x: "1" if i in x else "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with comparing each value with `df1.A` as:

```
pd.DataFrame({val:(df1.A.str.contains(val)).map(int) for val in df2.B.unique()})
```

If you want to combine it with `df1`, just use `pd.concat()`:

```
pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame({val:(df1.A.str.contains(val)).map(int) for val in df2.B.unique()})], axis =1)
```